# Group homomorphism and kernel

Tags: group-theory

Literally no idea where to begin this proof.

> $f$ is a homomorphism from $\{G, *\}$ to $\{ H, \circ\}$. Show that for any element $a \in G$: $\{g \in G | f(g) = f(a) \} = a * \ker ( f )$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: I am trying to learn a new branch of mathematics by working my way through a textbook over the summer - not part of a course or school, nor am I taking an exam at the end of it.  I am considering the way the textbook had previously demonstrated showing sets are equal by showing they are both subsets of the other, but I didn't get very far with that at all.

Comment: If you really have 'literally no idea' then you probably need to go back over earlier sections of your book. By my comment I meant that you are more likely to get a detailed answer if you show some initial working and thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(g)=f(a) \implies f(a^{-1}*g)=e_H \implies a^{-1}*g \in ker(f)\implies g\in a*ker(f)$$

$$g \in a* ker(f) \implies f(g) = f(a) \diamond e_H=f(a)$$

Comment: Thanks - the only part of it I don't follow is the last implication on the top line.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: The part I'm unsure of is $g*a^{-1}\in ker(f)\implies g\in a*ker(f)$

Comment: Is that ok now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $f(g)=f(a) \Leftrightarrow f(g)f(a)^{-1}=e$, where $e$ is the neutral element of the group $H$.